# Com объект word закрывает открытые файлы

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, com

```
import win32com.client 
import os
try:
    rootdir = os.getcwd()
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
    app.Visible = False
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            fullpath = os.path.join(*[subdir, file])
            if file.endswith(".doc"):
                in_file = os.path.abspath(rootdir + "\\" + file)
                doc = app.Documents.Open(in_file)
                content = doc.Content.Text
                print(content)
                doc.Close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    app.Quit()
```

Имею следующий код, проблема в том, что если его запустить имея открытыми несколько .doc файлов, то он все их закроет, прежде чем начать работу, как можно избавиться от этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закомментируйте:

```
app.Visible = False
```

и

```
app.Quit()
```

---

У меня так получилось:

```
import os
import win32com.client

try:
    rootdir = os.getcwd()
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if not file.endswith(".doc"):
                continue

            fullpath = os.path.join(root, file)

            doc = app.Documents.Open(fullpath, Visible=False)
            content = doc.Content.Text
            print(content)
            
            doc.Close()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Если закомментировать app.Quit(), то ничего не меняется, если закомментировать его вместе с app.Visible, то на моем экране видно, как открываются обрабатываемые ворд файлы, мне хочется, чтобы функция app.Visible = False оставалась в фунционале (файлы обрабатывались без демонстрации у меня на экране их открытия), но при этом чтобы остальные открытые вордовские файлы не закрывались

Comment: `app.Visible = False` скроет уже открытые документы ворд, а `app.Quit()` их потом закроет

Comment: Попробуйте у doc вызывать `doc.Visible = False` и соответственно у doc вызывать `Close()`. Из спеки: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb237305%28v%3doffice.12%29 и https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb217237%28v%3doffice.12%29

Comment: Конкретно на doc.Visible = False выдает - Property 'Open.Visible' can not be set, возможно нужно как-то обращаться к конкретному doc объекту, но у меня мало опыта в этой области

Comment: @ПавелКовтун `doc = app.Documents.Open(in_file, Visible=False)`

Comment: Visible = False в параметрах Open не срабатывает, видно как открывается файл

Comment: Вернее видно, если уже открыт какой-то документ заранее

Comment: Думаю, открытые документы видимы, потому что при открытии документа вызывается Visible=False

Comment: Открытые документы заранее и должны быть видны, но если ворд уже запущен до начала работы программы, то Visible=False игнорируется, это плохо :( очень хотелось бы как-то решить

Comment: @ПавелКовтун, и вправду, при открытых документах, Visible=False похоже игнорируется. Похоже это фича, поэтому предлагаю ее игнорировать :)

Comment: Возможно есть еще какие-то решения, которые позволят избежать этого

Comment: @ПавелКовтун мб, но я их не знаю. Предлагаю тему закрыть -- на вопрос я уже ответил, а для текущей ситуации с видимыми документами лучше отдельный вопрос задавать